# Makefile variable assignment error in echo

Tags: makefile

I have make file target like this

```
foo: 
    i = 1
    @echo $(i)
```

when I run the make file like this:

```
$ make foo
```

**i = 1

make: i: Command not found

Makefile:2: recipe for target 'foo' failed

make:  [foo] Error 127**

But if I do not give spaces in assignment (i.e)

```
i=1
```

Then no errors but no output, value of i is not printed

Answer (score 8):

The first attempt runs the command `i` with the parameters `=` and `2`. A proper assignment in the shell has [no spaces on either side of the equals sign.](/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment)

Your second problem is that a recipe on two physical lines will run two unrelated shell instances.  The first sets a variable to a value, then exits and loses the variable. The second, unrelated instance has no idea what the first did, and of course has no trace of the variable assignment.  The fix for that is to merge the two into a single line logically (you can still split the lines over several physical lines as long as you have a semicolon between them):

```
foo: 
    i=1; \
    echo "$${i}"
```

Notice also how we need to double the dollar signs in order to prevent `make` from interpreting them; and the [proper use of quotes around strings in the shell.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) (In this particular case we know the string doesn't contain any shell metacharacters; but many beginners stumble over this as well.)

GNU Make alternatively allows you to specify [`.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html) which forces the commands in the recipe to be evaluated all in a single shell instance;

```
.ONESHELL:
foo: 
    i=1
    echo "$${i}"
```

Comment: Separately, don't litter your `makefile` with `@`, especially not while debugging. Once it works, if you don't want to see what it's doing, run it with `make -s`

Answer (score 4):

In the first case you instruct the `make` to run a shell command: `i = 1`.

If you want a variable inside `Makefile` you should set without leading spaces/tabs.

I assume you use GNU's `make` and you want to check [Recipe Syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipe-Syntax.html#Recipe-Syntax) (or similar for other `make`s):

> A variable definition in a “rule context” which is indented by a tab
>   as the first character on the line, will be considered part of a
>   recipe, not a make variable definition, and passed to the shell.

Comment: Thank you. How to print the value of i?

Comment: `echo ${i}`, as you wrote :)

Comment: No, it is still not giving output using your syntax echo ${i}  and echo $(i). I do not see the 1 printed in the stdout.

Comment: What is your `Makefile`?

Comment: foo: 
    i=1
    @echo $(i)

Comment: Did you write `i=1` at the begin of line? Without tab/spaces prefix?

Comment: No, not at the beginning, not as a make variable. Sorry this windows does not allow proper format. I have declared i=1 without any spaces under the target foo: